# wxPhyton error loading a image failed to load image from file

Tags: python, image, wxpython

I have an error on wxPhyton. When I try to load and image It gives me this error:

```
"Failed to load image from file14:25:14:'resources/AboutPlatformDUT255b.bmp' 
can't open file 'resources/AboutPlatformDUT255b.bmp' (error 0: la operación se completó correctamente.)
14:25:14: Failed to load image from file "resources/AboutPlatformDUT255b.bmp".
```

I try to change the format between jpg, png, bmp and to resize the resolution but doesn't works. Any idea?

Comment: What does that error message say? Maybe it will be useful.

Comment: Try using a full path to the file instead of a relative one.

Comment: This is the message; 9:29:02: ----Can't open file 'resources/AboutPlatformDUT255.jpg' (error 0: la operación se completó correctamente.)
09:29:02: Failed to load image from file "resources/AboutPlatformDUT255.jpg"----. I try to change the path but doesn`t works. Probably is something related to the image because If I try other images it works. I put the code::::::::self.m_bitmap2 = wx.StaticBitmap( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap( u"resources/AboutPlatformDUT255.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG ), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

The problem was the path of the image file. I don´t not why but I can`t get the absolut path to show some images.